# JPA Entity Lifecycle Events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
@Entity
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = "evaluation_form")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE {h-schema}evaluation_form SET status = 0 WHERE id=? AND version = ?")
@Where(clause="status <> 0")
public class EvaluationForm extends ExPersistableEntity<String> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;
    private String code;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    private String name;
    private String biddingCode;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(255)")
    private String biddingName;
    private String biddingType;
    private String biddingMethod;
    private String state;
    private String biddingForm;
```

I want to ask if there is any way to save the adding, editing, and deleting actions of the table
please help me

Comment: I want to save the history of adding, editing, and deleting actions

Comment: You used quotes instead of a code block. I've updated the formatting for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can log all activities in the entity by using class AuditTrailListener.

you can find it here
[JPA Entity Lifecycle Events](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events)
and here
[Auditing with JPA, Hibernate, and Spring Data JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)